# Pandas rolling window not working with "closed" interval

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'm trying to utilize a rolling window with a closed interval, however, for some reason the "closed" function is not working.

I've tried implementing the following (based on the example from the Pandas documentation found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html)):

```
a = pd.DataFrame(range(5), index=pd.date_range('2020', periods=5))
b = a.assign(
    sum_left=a.rolling(2, closed='left').sum(),
    sum_right=a.rolling(2, closed='right').sum(),
    sum_both=a.rolling(2, closed='both').sum(),
    sum_neither=a.rolling(2, closed='neither').sum(),
)
b
```

The result should be:

```
Out[27]: 
                     x  right  both  left  neither
2013-01-01 09:00:01  1    1.0   1.0   NaN      NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1    2.0   2.0   1.0      1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  1    2.0   3.0   2.0      1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:04  1    2.0   3.0   2.0      1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  1    1.0   2.0   1.0      NaN
```

However, I receive:

```
0   sum_left    sum_right   sum_both    sum_neither
2020-01-01  0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-01-02  1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2020-01-03  2   3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0
2020-01-04  3   5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0
2020-01-05  4   7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0
```

Any idea why the function is not running?

My pandas version is: '1.1.3'

Comment: I tested your code and it worked as expected for me (pandas version = 1.2.1). It might be a bug related to its version '1.1.3'. The expected output, however, isn't what you said "The result should be". Please make sure you properly understood the role of `closed`. Best!

Comment: it was a bug! https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34315